# boot delay (of my own making) in 21.10 and post-boot delays in launching chrome

Tags: boot, ssh, google-chrome, virtualization, gui

At the moment I am using 21.10 on a desktop as a very average user, using such applications as a browser and occasionally Open Office. It takes about 5+ minutes for the computer to boot because I have applications that I installed to learn Virtualisation etc., which I no longer need on this particular desktop. Please advise me from the attached screenshot (or from any other command output that you need), what needs to be stopped, disabled and purged.

The published post does not show the image URL, posting it again as code `https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2vx1.jpg`

I had installed google computing engine in my desktop (with the idea that it was required for os-auth), this was unnecessary, I have already disabled these applications.

Post boot, chrome takes over a minute to launch, zoom also takes about as much time. There is some problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit tricky.

I'd recommend trying to find the non-essential packages you installed and remove them.

One way to find big packages is

```
sudo apt install debian-goodies
dpigs -n 30 -H
```

Then you can hopefully find and remove some non-essential packages which are slowing your boot down.

If all else fails or you can't find what you installed, I would reinstall.

Also - check with htop if you have non-essential programs residing in RAM which are started automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed debian-goodies, pasted the output of dpigs and also system-analyze here:  [ubuntu pastebin link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Vp6KczkCyB/) @colindaven